# Unable to find eclipse.ini file in snap

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, snap, jvm

I have installed eclipse in Ubuntu 16.04 via Snap. And in the snap folder, I can see eclipse.

```
ls -al snap/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 croy croy 4096 May 27 14:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 49 croy croy 4096 May 27 14:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 croy croy 4096 May 27 14:04 eclipse
drwxr-xr-x  4 croy croy 4096 May 19 12:24 notepad-plus-plus
drwxr-xr-x  6 croy croy 4096 May 22 18:13 skype
drwxr-xr-x  4 croy croy 4096 May 27 14:06 vscode
```

I am looking for `eclipse.ini` file
And the `/snap/eclipse/` folder, there is no file.

```
ls -al snap/eclipse
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 croy croy 4096 May 27 14:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 croy croy 4096 May 27 14:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 croy croy 4096 May 27 14:04 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 croy croy 4096 May 27 14:04 common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 croy croy    2 May 27 14:04 current -> 12
```

There is a symbolic link between `12` & `current` folder but I can't see any file in any of the folder.
But If I do - `sudo find / -name eclipse.ini` it gives me the following result

```
/snap/eclipse/12/eclipse.ini
```

Where/how I can find the `eclipse.ini` file to change `jvm` argument

Answer (score 1):

```
/snap/eclipse/current$ ls -ltr
total 345
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 140566 Mar 30 17:31 icon.xpm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  71473 Mar 30 17:31 eclipse
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 137930 Apr  5 20:25 artifacts.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root    586 Apr  5 20:25 eclipse.ini
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root      3 Apr  5 20:25 dropins
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    178 Apr 13 21:13 eclipse.desktop
drwxrwxr-x 64 root root   3707 Apr 13 21:16 features
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root     42 Apr 13 21:17 readme
drwxrwxr-x 14 root root  30835 Apr 13 21:17 plugins
drwxrwxr-x  4 root root     87 Apr 13 21:17 p2
drwxrwxr-x  4 root root    105 Apr 13 21:17 configuration
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     58 Apr 13 21:17 snap
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     43 Apr 13 21:17 meta
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     36 Apr 13 21:17 command-eclipse.wrapper
```

The eclipse.ini file should be present in the **/snap/eclipse/current** directory as shown above. However you won't be able to edit eclipse.ini file. This is because snap applications are by default mounted on another read-only file system. Even sudo permissions do not work.

Comment: So via snap installation, I can't modify JVM argument.